Could a jet powered tail-sitter aircraft compete with standard VTOL designs?
There have been many designs for tail-sitters1 in the past, but they were mostly scrapped for being really hard to land and take off in. However, today this can be easily mitigated with computers. They may also be harder to arm and service, but I don't think this is enough to kill the concept since it would do away with the lift fan, allowing for more efficient VTOL(although no STOL capability, but that's not always available).
Thus the question, in what areas could a tailsitter have an advantage over conventional VTOL craft?

1 A "tail-sitter" aircraft is one that naturally sits upright on its tail (vertical) vs. horizontally on landing gear. Such an aircraft would "lift off" rather than "take off," but it would begin and end flight from the tail-sitting position vs. horizontally on landing gear.

What is a tail sitter? Is it the same thing as a tail dragger? Why would a tail dragger aircraft be better at vertical take-off and landing? After all, it's vertical, so that all the wheels touch the ground at same time no matter if you have one in front of the other two, or one aft the other two. (Large tail draggers have the problem that the main landing gear needs to be placed waaaaay forward, where there is most usually no natural place for it.)

@AlexP Google it(tail-sitting aircraft), it's way different than a tail dragger. The plane starts sitting on its tail, facing upwards, and takes off straight up using the engine to push it up. Then it transitions into horizontal flight. Examples include the Pogo and the Conecopter. The upside is you don't need to pivot the engine or have a lift fan, downside its difficult to fly a plane like that, which is why it was killed. I thought computers might fix that.

Compete in what way? Every design is about tradeoffs without knowing what aspects are important and which aren't you cannot meaningfully compare two designs.

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a worldbuilding question. At best, it's a question for an engineering stack. If the purpose of the quesiton is to ascertain a story or plot element (the nature of the competition), then it's off-topic as, per the [help/on-topic], we don't help people tell stories. In a worldbuilding context, whether one can compete with the other is the OP's sole choice. We can help rationalize that choice - but we do not make it.

@JBH Isn't that covered in the second part, being "What's needed for it to compete"?

@Bubbles Do you mean the second question that shouldn't exist because questions are literally closed for asking more than one question? (Bear in mind I'm making a point....)

@JBH Seems like one question to me? What could make them compete if they don't already?

@Bubbles Asking, "A, but if not A then B" is two questions: A and B. In your case, A = Could a tail-sitter compete with current VTOL designs? and B = Are there technologies we don't currently have that would allow them to compete? They're two questions because one person may provide a reasonable answer to A and another, not as versed as the first, would assume A can't be answered and answer B, so two sets of answers. Two sets of answers, two questions.

@JBH Ok, thanks. I think it's too late to edit now as there are already answers but I'll keep that in mind.

Please specify what you mean by "compete", or what the competition is. Faster, longer range, more payload, ... ? Also, are you specifically asking about planes, because helicopters are VTOL aircraft too

I do not think so
This is going to piggy-back on John Dallmans answer a little bit - as everything they said was a good answer.
But it misses IMO the biggest factor:
The ability to operate from non-conventional airfields
Alright kiddos - time for a little history lesson. The original ventures into VTOL were made in the 50s. The reason for this was a genuine fear that in WW3, the Soviets would target all of the airfields and without runways, the conventional air fleet would be neutered.
The enemy would have air-superiority in Europe and then it would be a stalemate between the USA and the USSR with an Ocean between them.
So - a means by which you could have the Flight speed, Carrying capacity of a Jet Aircraft, but with the landing and take-off ability of a Helicopter (meaning it can be landed in a field or closer to the front line or even moved about) was a major advantage.
Entire the Harrier Jump Jet (Cue the obnoxious playing of Rule Britannia on loop)
It could land anywhere, take-off vertically with a partial combat load (which if you are only located say 30 miles away from the frontline is less of an issue compared to an airfield that is 300 miles away)
With just a fuel bowser, a ground generator and supply of Ordinance, a group of Airmen could refuel and resupply a Harrier and send it back to the front line with minimal specialist equipment
500 pound bombs can be handloaded, Unguided rockets, sidewinders etc. all re-attached without the need for specialist equipment.
Now - to compare to a tail-standing aircraft. You have the issue of Height. a Harrier is 14 metres long, Aircraft, generally want to be long and slender for Aerodynamic reasons - so even if we use one of the shortest conventional Jet fights - the Folland Gnat - that is still 9 metres long - you need a pretty long ladder, or a means to get the pilot in and out - then you have to have a winch or crane or loader or similar, specialist heavy equipment to reload and refuel the aircraft - to get the items up to where the wings would be.
Furthermore - there is the issue of concealment. Yes, a Harrier, with its vertical tailplane is tall, but a tail-standing jet is really tall - and such a large vertical object would be really easy to pick-out with the reconnaissance means of the day.
So to conclude - if we consider the original historical context of how and why these types of aircraft were designed and built - No, I do not believe they would compete.
However
There is one area where a Vertically standing Jet could have an advantage:
Carrier Operations
Space on a Carrier flight deck is at a huge premium - and we have seen all sorts of folding wing arrangements to minimize the amount of space an Airframe takes up on the Carrier - there is potential that a Vertically stored Airframe could have some advantages here - although I would be worried about the pitching and rolling of the deck - there may be a scenario where the increased carrying capacity (say a 50 percent increase) is significant enough to work around these challenges.

The problems with a tail sitter jet certainly included the difficulty of controlling the aircraft on landing but computers alone won't solve the problem of the pilot having limited visibility.
A conventional VTOL jet might not have a great view for landing either but the pilot will at least be sitting upright and have something like a 270˚ view around to see landing markers.  A pilot sitting with his back to the tarmac isn't likely to be able to see much.  I can think of a number of ways to mitigate this but they come with drawbacks.
Consider a second member of the crew that is facing backwards that will perform the functions of a weapon systems officer in flight but then become the pilot on landing.  This means having what could be a great view, or at least and acceptable one, but could end up in the uncomfortable position of hanging from his safety harness during takeoff and any rapid acceleration while in evasive maneuvers.
Perhaps the pilot, or even a 2 man crew if the mission calls for it, sit in a kind of ball turret on the front that can pivot from a vertical takeoff/landing position to a horizontal position for normal flight.  This would obviously be heavy and complex, but maybe not as heavy and complex as the moving nozzles on a conventional VTOL aircraft.  I can imagine such a system would be very complex, even if it could be made lighter, and could have drawbacks on a rapid evacuation or ejection if there's a problem.
Then is the matter of taxiing the aircraft on the ground.  A conventional VTOL jet can do some, if not all, taxiing under it's own power with simple controls.  How would a tail-sitter do this?  I can think up a few options but I doubt any would be all that practical.
Maybe there's a means to produce a practical tail-sitter aircraft but nobody has thought it up yet.  Advancements in computers, new materials and manufacturing, as well as a lot more experience in VTOL aircraft, certainly gives us a lot more to work with that didn't exist when tail-sitter aircraft were first considered.  What this experience may have taught us is that a tail-sitter design doesn't offer enough advantages over a conventional design to be worth pursuing.

Can't most modern planes(At least airliners) pretty much land themselves now? Also, the Conecopter had a functioning rotating seat that helped with landing, and the pilot was able to land it, so that seems doable. I don't see how it could taxi without help either though, so that would be a drawback.

This looks rather hard to build and operate, for several reasons:
The undercarriage will be weird
You'll certainly need some kind of undercarriage, so that the jet nozzle stays clear of the ground, and to absorb shocks when landing. But it's at the back of the aircraft, which is unhelpful for the centre of gravity.
A tail-sitter also can't taxi under its own engine power, and the centre of gravity when it's on the ground will be rather high up, presenting a risk of it tipping over. That last point would be a problem on aircraft carriers, where the "ground" can move about quite a bit, and tilt to significant angles.
You need a lot of engine power, which has drawbacks
Harriers and F-35Bs can't make vertical take-offs with a full war-load. They make rolling or ski-jump take-offs so that wing lift helps them get off the ground.
A tail-sitter needs enough engine power to take off with its full load. On the plus side, this means it will have excellent acceleration and rate of climb, but it will be notably thirsty for fuel, and have a shorter range than a more conventional aircraft.
Assuming that it's required to be supersonic, it will have normal-size air intakes, like an F-35B, rather than the huge intakes of a Harrier. The drag of those intakes is why Harriers are subsonic. The F-35B does its vertical flight largely via the LiftFan, a huge fan that moves large quantities of air slowly, driven by shaft power from the main engine. Moving lots of air slowly gets you a much better thrust-to-fuel ratio than moving smaller quantities of air quickly.
A tail-sitter seems obliged to get thrust the inefficient way, which means its exhaust will be very hard on the surfaces it lands on and takes off from. Harriers need concrete or metal, and tear up tarmac. F-35Bs need special coatings on metal flight decks to avoid damaging them. This will be worse.
If the landing computer goes wrong, you have to crash-land or eject
If you know it has failed, you can try a belly-landing, or eject. If you don't know it has gone bad, you probably die, because the ejection seat will be firing at a slight downward slope, and has very little space to pull out before it hits something. Fighter pilots are really expensive to train and keep in practice; if they are not confident in their aircraft, they are a lot less effective.

Those are interesting points, but some of it feels a bit contrived eg the ejection going down... Just point it in a different direction? There have been successful ejection seats for tail-sitters. Or that the engines consume more fuel in normal flight...throttle back?

The other critical failure mode is running out of fuel/blocked fuel line/engine failure - a Harrier or F-35B that loses power can try for a deadstick landing on its undercarriage if it finds a flat stretch of ground such as a sealed road.  A tail-sitter will have no undercarriage to glide to a landing on, and most designs have significant protrusions on the ventral surface at the rear for the undercarriage that would rip it apart if it tried a belly landing.

"If the landing computer goes wrong" is not a very valid consideration. Highly modern VTOL aircraft already have computers in the "critical path" to functioning, and straight-up do not work if the computer does not work. For example, the F35 is a software-defined plane, which means that if the computer is offline, you are ejecting, and that's it.

@KerrAvon2055 Actually, the US version(Pogo) was capable of belly landings by ejecting the ventral fin, so there are ways to do a belly landing.
